# random_state.shuffle is throwing exceptions in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to call the random_state.shuffle method in Python and keep getting the following error:

```
 random_state.shuffle(class_data)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4417, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.shuffle
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

I have initialized random_state as shown below:

```
random_state = np.random.RandomState(100)
```

After that I try to create SFrame:

```
def build_bitmap_sframe():
    bitmaps_list, labels_list = [], []
    for category in categories:
        class_data = np.load(os.path.join(bitmap_directory, category + ".npy"))
        print(class_data)
        random_state.shuffle(class_data) # this line error
```

What am I missing?

Here is the link for docs: https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/drawing_classifier/data-preparation.html

Comment: What type of object is ```class_data```? ```random_state.shuffle``` only takes array-like arguments (lists or npy arrays)